# split and increase in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `productID="ab1002"` which is in string format.
`productID` is not always start with `ab` it might be `xy`,`ptz`.So i want to split the numeric part of ID and increase by 1.
means 
`string productID="ab1002";`
want a result
 `string newProductID="ab1003";`

How to get this.thanks for help.

Comment: Hello @ShreeKhanal, would you please check my answer and please let me know, thats working fine accordingly, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello @ShreeKhanal, have you ever checked your accepted answer? That doesn't work and that is why I told you to check my answer, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Md works or not is not a major thing i want a flow how to do it and able to find when i got a correct direction.

Comment: Hello @ShreeKhanal, I know you! Certainly what you're thinking is absolutely wrong, however, it is simple that accepted answer should provide desired output, there are lots of way to achieve goal, do whatever you like I'm not bothering of that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the characters:

```
string sNumbers = Regex.Replace(productID,"[^A-Z][a-z]",String.Empty); // To remove letters
string sText = Regex.Replace(productID,"[^0-9]",String.Empty); // To remove numbers
string iTmp = int.Parse(sNumbers); // Convert to integer
iTmp++; 

string newProductID = sText + iTmp.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got what i want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try with below code, this works fine according to you, thanks for your time

```
productID = (Regex.Replace(productID, "[0-9]", String.Empty)) +
                (Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(productID, "[a-z]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) + 1).ToString();
```

Comment: Hello @ShreeKhanal, but your accepted answer is working always!, However this works fine and so may I may get a vote, thanks for your time.